# How do I make a map's background transparent in a layout?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts, qgis-print-layouts, map-overviews

I am trying to add an overview map to my layout. The main map is projected while the overview map is a 'globe' (image below). I want to make the white part of the overview map transparent.

[image]

I have made the background transparent in page properties and I have turned off background for both maps. There is no option to make the background of the main QGIS window transparent.

Is there anything else I can do other than export separately and add it as an image with transparency values?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I have looked at [How to export a map with a transparent background in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193579/how-to-export-a-map-with-a-transparent-background-in-qgis/193584) but it didn't work.

Comment: I turned off background for the smaller map and it became transparent.

Comment: Hi @Erik, see my own answer below. I'm just having a slow day. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I'm just an idiot.

I forgot that I had an inverted polygon turned on to add some fading to the outer edge. The solid fill of this was filling the rest of the layout.

Thanks anyways.