# "Export map to image" with a transparent background in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, export

I need to export (a lot of) images from QGIS using the "export map to image" command and I need them to have a transparent background.

Is that possible, and how could I achieve it?

Comment: Not sure about QGIS. How about having an unique background color and just choose the color code as transparent in a image processing software like gimp or photoshop?

Comment: because it would be too much work - I have a LOT of images to export ::)

Comment: [How about this?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193579/how-to-export-a-map-with-a-transparent-background-in-qgis)